# Understanding the proof of L'Hopital's theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis

This proof is from N. Piskunov Differential and Integral Calculus:
[image]

I am clear up to "as $x$ approaches $a$, $\xi$ approaches $a$". But I am not sure how to make sense of the statement after that, that is that the limits mentioned are equivalent. It makes intuitive sense that as both $x$ and $\xi$ approach $a$, whilst still fulfilling Cauchy's theorem, then those limits approach the same value but is there a more formal way to prove a form like that?

Comment: You will get it immediately if you write $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then you want to prove that there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-a|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(x)}{\varphi(x)}-A\right|<\varepsilon.$$But, since $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{\varphi'(x)}=A$, you now that there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-a|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f'(x)}{\varphi'(x)}-A\right|<\varepsilon.$$So, if $|x-a|<\delta$, then, since $\xi$ lies somewhere between $x$ and $a$, you also have $|\xi-a|<\delta$, and therefore$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{\varphi(x)}-A\right|=\left|\frac{f'(\xi)}{\varphi'(\xi)}-A\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have a slightly stupid question. I don't have much experience with proofs containing delta-epsilon. I get that for each $|x-a|<\delta$ there exists a xi such that $|\xi-a|<\delta$. But why can we substute xi for x in the next step?

Comment: For *every* $x$ in $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, I have $\left|\frac{f'(x)}{\varphi'(x)}-A\right|\varepsilon$. So, if I take a particular $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, then, since $\xi$ lies somewhere between that $x$ and $a$, then I know that $\xi\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ too, and therefore $\left|\frac{f'(\xi)}{\varphi'(\xi)}-A\right|\varepsilon$.